# PHPUnit custom assertion message

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm writing a custom assertion to be used with PHPUnit but I see two (2) error messages whenever I place a custom one.

The code:

```
$this->_testCase->assertThat(
    $hasMessageCode,
    $this->_testCase->isTrue(),
   "Failed asserting that API response contains a message whose code is {$code}."
);
```

The output:

```
1) ApiTest::testFoo
Failed asserting that API response contains an error whose code is REG012.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Is there any way I can only output the *custom* message and skip the second one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that PHPUnit immediately evaluates the test and then outputs, if it creates some kind of list which is later evaluated this may not work. Not the cleanest solution, but you could mess with the output buffer.

```
public function whateverFunctionYouHave($hasMessageCode) {
  ob_start();
  $this->_testCase->assertThat(
    $hasMessageCode,
    $this->_testCase->isTrue(),
   "Failed asserting that API response contains a message whose code is {$code}."
  );
  $out = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $expectedDefaultMessage = "Failed asserting that false is true.";
  if (strpos($out, $expectedDefaultMessage) !== false) {
    $out = str_replace($expectedDefaultMessage, "");
    echo $out; 
  }
}
```

Little late to the party, but...that *should* work.